# xinit: giving up can't start xinit

Tags: xinit

My Musicbot won't start:

```
musikbot@euve102733:/opt/ts3soundboard$ xinit /opt/ts3soundboard/ts3bot -- /usr/bin/ Xvfb :1 -screen 0 800x600x16 -ac

xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

What can I do about this?